# React-Toggle side menu className

Tags: reactjs

This is not something new but for me doing toggle among the side menu item is bit challenging in React application. Please have a look in code and suggest the possible solution:

Here I have multiple menu item and if I click on perticular menu item it should show selected/active:

```
 <div  className="offcanvas offcanvas-start sidebar-nav theme-custom-gray"
    tabindex="-1"
    id="sidebar">     
          <ul>
            <li>              
                <i>
                Dashboard              
            </li>
            <li><hr /></li>
            <li>              
                product              
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#layouts">
                <i>
                Create New             
                    <i>
              </a>
                  <ul>
                  <li>                    
                      MenuItem                    
                  </li>
                  <li>                    
                      product 1                    
                  </li>
                  <li>                    
                      product 2
                    
                  </li>
                  <li>                    
                      product 3
                    
                  </li>
                </ul>              
            </li>
            <li>              
                <i>
                View List              
            </li>
            <li><hr /></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: how do you toggle this? there should be an `onClick={toggleFunc}` in one of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

`App.jsx`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const menuItems = ["MenuItem 1", "MenuItem 2", "MenuItem 3", "MenuItem 4"];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedMI, setSelectedMI] = useState(menuItems[0]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
        <li
          className={selectedMI === menuItem ? "selected" : ""}
          onClick={() => setSelectedMI(menuItem)}
        >
          {menuItem}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`styles.css`:

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, but one thing here href is also need dynamic binding.

Thank you!!!